# How to create door animation in react native

Tags: css, react-native, animation

I want to create a door animation using react native, but i don't know exactly how to do that,

i just can animated *Flip Card* transition like this:

[image: transition]

anyone can help me how to create a door animation?

`Current code`:

```
export default class Home2 extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.anim = new Animated.Value(0)
  }

  startAnim(){
    this.anim.setValue(0)
    Animated.spring(this.anim, {
      toValue:1,
      useNativeDriver:false
    }).start()
  }

  render() {
    const animated = this.anim.interpolate({
      inputRange:[0, 1],
      outputRange:['80deg', '0deg']
    })
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', backgroundColor:'red'}}>
        <Animated.View style={{width:100, height:100, backgroundColor:'white', transform:[{rotateY:animated}]}}/>
        <Button
          onPress={() => {
            this.startAnim()
          }}
          title="Start"
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
transform-origin: left; // THIS WILL TRANSFORM YOUR DIV TO THE LEFT AND YOU 
JUST NEED TO ADD BACKGROUND COLOR FOR EFFECT
```

here is full code on codepen https://codepen.io/am_eu/pen/EgZdaQ